# After ejecting the react-native app to android when i run 'npm run android' it gives error saying tools.jar is missing?

Tags: android, react-native

When i try to run `npm run android` command it gives following error. It said to check jdk in jre folder?

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201 contains a valid JDK installation.
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.